# Delete records with Self Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table called VirtualFileSystem that stores the file structure of a project folder. It has below columns:

id, Name, parent_id and Is_folder

where parent_id is a foreign key to primary column id.

Now i need to write a query to delete empty folders, that is delete records if id is not used as parent_id (if its not used as parent means its empty folder) and is_folder is True.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Here is sample data, First and second rows are folders, third and fourth records are files present in first row/folder. Second record/folder is empty as no record contains its id as parent_id. So, i want to write a query to delete second row.

```
id, name,     parent_id, is_folder
-------------------------------
1,   folder1, null,       T
2,   folder2, null,       T
1_0, file0,   1,          F
1_1, file1,   1,          F
```

Comment: provide some sample data

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from VirtualFileSystem 
where id not in 
(
   select distinct parent_id from VirtualFileSystem
)
and Is_folder = 'T'
```

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina are you sure you've selected the proper automatic answer? juergen d is a member for more than eight years now. Nevertheless, the answer could benefit from some explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE A
FROM VirtualFileSystem AS A
LEFT JOIN VirtualFileSystem AS B
    ON A.id = B.parent_id
WHERE A.is_folder = 'T'
    AND B.id IS NULL
```